# Is there a way to include labels within a 3D plot?

Tags: label, wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

If I have a plot like

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Piecewise[{{x^2,0<x<1},{x^(-1),1<x<3}}],{x,0,3}]
```

is there anyone to add labels *within* the plot?

For example, if I wanted to label specifically the position x=1 as something like "Enters magnetic field," is there any way I could do it?

Comment: Show[Graphics3D[Text["Enters magnetic field", {1, 0, 0}]],
 RevolutionPlot3D[
  Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 < x < 1}, {x^(-1), 1 < x < 3}}], {x, 0, 3}]
 ]

Comment: Thank you. Would you please tell me how I could then do two labels of text or point me to instructions that could explain how?

Comment: Look at the help page for Show to see what it accepts. Or try this: Show[Graphics3D[Text["Enters magnetic field", {1, 0, 0}]], 
 Graphics3D[Text["Exits magnetic field", {-1, 0, 0}]], 
 RevolutionPlot3D[Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 < x < 1}, {x^(-1), 1 < x < 3}}], {x, 0, 3}]] And click on Details and Options on the help page for Text to learn about positioning text relative to a particular point.